# What is “peace or comfort”?

Tags: england-and-wales, eviction

The Protection from Eviction Act 1977 refers in a handful of places to “peace or comfort.” What is the meaning and scope of the referents of this phrase? Is it confined merely to that immediate peace and comfort within the premises of the property in question? Or is it more general? Have any cases addressed this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The phrase "peace *or* comfort" is used in only two places of the [Act](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1977/43) as part of the description of an offence known as harassment at s. 1(3A).

The [First-Tier Tribunal, Property Chamber explains](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/media/642198265155a2000c6ad7c9/202022_0006_6_Wilberforce_Court_London_SE28_8AB__RRO_March_2023___002_.pdf):

> 14. With regard to unlawful eviction and harassment if a party does acts likely to
>     interfere with the peace or comfort of the residential occupier or members of
>     his household then this amounts to an offence.
> 15. Dealing first with harassment what might constitute such conduct by the
>     landlord. Harassment can be anything a landlord does, or fails to do, that makes
>     you feel unsafe in the property or forces you to leave. Harassment can include
>     stopping services, like electricity. withholding keys, for example there are 2
>     tenants in a property, but the landlord will only give 1 key. Similar acts of
>     harassment could be refusing to carry out repairs anti-social behaviour by a
>     landlord’s agent, for example a friend of the landlord moves in next door and
>     causes problems or threats and physical violence.

Comment: Okay, and good find, but it still doesn’t directly address what is meant by the specific componental phrase of “peace or comfort“. It only gives some examples of things which may constitute the offence.